# Does anyone know where this weird blue and green laughing chess set is from?

Tags: identify-this-game, chess, identify-this-game-piece

I found this really weird chess set at a thrift store. Does anyone know where it’s from? (I bought it because, obviously).
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you really want to play chess, I suggest that you orient the board correctly : the lower-right hand corner square should be a light square, not a dark one. Not doing so would invert the positions of the queens and the kings...

Comment: But note that Umbra either considers Blue to be white and Green to be black or don't know the rules of chess, either. The packaging shows blue on the right (and it's sown more clearly on the back).

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson : That is terribly confusing. However, in that case, the pieces on their packaging are correctly set up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a "playmate" chess set by Umbra. UPC: 028295167055

[image]